# How to change div contents with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, radio-button, onchange

This seems simple but I don't know what I'm doing really. I have 2 radio buttons and depending on which one is selected the contents of a div will change. Right now I have 2 divs inside a parent div but it would just hide one div and show the other. This wouldn't be bad if they didn't take up space even when they're invisible.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <form role="form">
        <div>
            <div class="radio" id="radioSelection" onchange="chooseDiv()">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="selectionDiv1" checked />Choose Div1
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="selectionDiv2" />Choose Div2
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="parentDiv">
    <div id="div1">You're Awesome!</div>
    <div id="div2">Everybody loves you!</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function chooseDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById("selectionDiv1").checked) {
        document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

So I'd like to have it so only one div is visible at a time depending on which radio button is checked, and don't have them take up space when they're not in the div. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want those divs to stop taking space, you have to use display:none instead of visibility:hidden, change your function to

```
function chooseDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById("selectionDiv1").checked) {
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/H4C9C7dAD324qJUgESMF?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

`visibility` property will always use the space whenever it is hidden.

Better approach would be to use `display` property.

Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("div2").style.display= "none"; //similar to hidden
document.getElementById("div1").style.display= "block"; // visible
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `visibility: hidden` to hide the divs, which hides them but let them take space in the browser, try instead the [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) property, instead of using `hidden` use `none`, and instead of using `visible` use `block`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand first the difference between the `display` and `visibility` properties.

**display - none** - when you do `display none` that means whole element from DOM will hide with its physical existence in DOM.So, there will be no space allocation for that element in DOM.

**Visibility - hidden** - In this case , you are hiding only that element but physically that element is present in that space.So, space will be allocate that element.

for more details please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 1):

Using just one div and change content

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/trbacxqq/3)

HTML

```
<body onload='chooseDiv();'>
<div>
    <form role="form">
        <div>
            <div class="radio" id="radioSelection" onchange="chooseDiv()">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="selectionDiv1" checked />Choose Div1
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="selectionDiv2" />Choose Div2
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="parentDiv">
    <div id="div1"></div>
</div>

<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='c1'><span>TEST 1</span><img src='http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=hiFacebook'/></div>
     <div id='c2'><span>TEST 2</span><img src='http://zelcs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/stackoverflow-logo-dumpster.jpg' /></div>
</div>

</body>
```

JS

```
   function chooseDiv() {
    var div = document.getElementById("div1");
    var msg =  document.getElementById("c1").innerHTML;

    if (!document.getElementById("selectionDiv1").checked) {
        msg = document.getElementById("c2").innerHTML;
    }

    div.innerHTML = msg;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is awesome but in my project i actually have graphs in each div, i just used the text to make the example easier to understand

Comment: Great, you can set html content inside innerHTML. ex: innerHTML = '<div><img src=xxx></div>'